# biber - warning about non-ascii characters

Tags: biblatex, biber, input-encodings

Biber gives me the following warning:

```
WARN - The entry 'csorgo__sandor:10' has characters
which cannot be encoded in 'ascii'. Recoding problematic
characters into macros.
```

Is this anything to worry about?  If not, why the warning?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[url=false,citestyle=verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{csorgo__sandor:10,
year={2008},
author={K\'{e}rchy, Cz\'{e}dli, G. and Hajnal, P. and others},
title={{S}\'{a}ndor {C}s\"{o}rg\H{o}, 1947-2008},
journal={Acta Sci. Math. (Szeged)},
pages={3-5},
volume={74},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is only a warning.  biber encodes to UTF8 and then decodes back to ascii, but has to use macros for some of the accents.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To get rid off the warning you can change the input code to utf8 for your `.tex`-file.

With the following changed MWE I have no warnings or errors from `biber` and only one warning with the `.tex`-file (because package `filecontents` generates this warning).  I marked the changes with `%!!!!!!!!`

Your MWE with some changes:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{csorgo__sandor:10,
  year    = {2008},
  author  = {K\'{e}rchy, Cz\'{e}dli, G. and Hajnal, P. and others},
  title   = {{S}\'{a}ndor {C}s\"{o}rg\H{o}, 1947--2008},
  journal = {Acta Sci. Math. (Szeged)},
  pages   = {3--5},
  volume  = {74},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    % utf8 support       %!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       % code for pdf file  %!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
\usepackage[url=false,citestyle=verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: so it's a compulsory to use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` for compiling non-ASCII characters in bibliography? Then what's the advantage of using XeLaTeX and pdfLaTeX?